# Found error when customer tried to login in

Tags: login, customer-account, magento2.2, exception, no-such-entity-exception

When customer tried to login, there always error log in exception log, here's the error written in exception log :

> main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No
>   such entity with customerId =  at
>   /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:49)"}
>   []

Is there something wrong that made that error log?

Comment: Have  you done reindexing?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same your issue. On dashboard tab, we don't get the first-name and the email. But on another tab we get the email and first-name (with the same code on same a file)

You can try the below code to get current customer

```php
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;
...

    /** @var CurrentCustomer */
    protected CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer;

    public function __construct(
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
    ) {
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Magento Customer Model for this block
     *
     * @return CustomerInterface|null
     */
    public function getCurrentCustomer(): ?CustomerInterface
    {
        try {
            return $this->currentCustomer->getCustomer();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```